# RxJS scan and combinelatest behavior

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have been learning RxJs and I am having issues trying to determine the logic behind output I am seeing when using scan and combinelatest

I have this sample application

```js
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var stream = subject.map(function(x) {
  return function(v) {
    return v + " stream";
  };
});

var state = Rx.Observable.merge(stream)
  .startWith("StartWith")
  .scan(function(x, f) {
    console.log("scan");
    return f(x);
  });

var view1 = state.map(function(x) {
  return "view1 " + x;
});

var view2 = state.map(function(x) {
  return " view2 " + x;
});

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(view1, view2, function(x, y) {
  return [x, y].join(",");
}).subscribe(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});

subject.onNext("Once");
subject.onNext("Twice");
```

When you look at the console logs for the application it outputs the follow

```
LOG: view1 StartWith, view2 StartWith, 
LOG: scan 
LOG: view1 StartWith stream, view2 StartWith, 
LOG: scan 
LOG: view1 StartWith stream, view2 StartWith stream, 
LOG: scan 
LOG: view1 StartWith stream stream, view2 StartWith stream, 
LOG: scan 
LOG: view1 StartWith stream stream, view2 StartWith stream stream,
```

I dont understand why the scan is called so often. I am only calling onNext twice for the subject yet it seems to be calling the scan function 4 times. If I add in more views it will add 2 more calls to scan and so on.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 7):

Its because you are subscribing to it twice. `CombineLatest` will implicitly subscribe to both of the streams that you are passing it. This is pretty common mistake when you first use Rx, that unless the operator claims to share the underlying observable for every subscription, each subscription will create a **new** Observable stream.

That is, your code above is pretty much functionally equivalent to the following (but don't actually do this):

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var source1 = subject
  .map(function(x) {
    return function(v) {
      return v + " stream";
    };
  })
  .startWith("StartWith")
  .scan(function(x, f) {
    console.log("scan");
    return f(x);
  }).map(function(x) {
    return "view1 " + x;
  });

var source2 = subject
  .map(function(x) {
    return function(v) {
      return v + " stream";
    };
  })
  .startWith("StartWith")
  .scan(function(x, f) {
    console.log("scan");
    return f(x);
  })
  .map(function(x) {
    return " view2 " + x;
  })


var x, y;

source1.subscribe(function(_x) { 
   x = _x;
   if (typeof y !== 'undefined') {  
     console.log([x, y].join(","));
   });

source2.subscribe(function(_y) { 
   y = _y;
   if (typeof x !== 'undefined') {
     console.log([x, y].join(","));
   });

subject.onNext("Once");
subject.onNext("Twice");
```

If you want to have scan only called once you should use [`share()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) after `scan()` so that the `Observable` from `scan` will be shared between subscribers.

So `state` should really be:

```
var state = Rx.Observable.merge(stream)
  .startWith("StartWith")
  .scan(function(x, f) {
    console.log("scan");
    return f(x);
  })
  .share();
```

Comment: @paulpdaniels could you please elaborate on what share does. The documentation takes me to some weird page which has seemingly nothing to do with `share()`.

Comment: @MysticofChaos `share()` really just wraps `publish().refCount()`. Essentially it will hook up the source `Observable` when the first `Observer` subscribes, and then it will share that `Observable` among all the subsequent `Observers`

Comment: Not sure what link you are using but here is the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) for it